# Script on processing 3

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I made a script that works on KhanAcademy but when I'm trying to execute it on the program processing 3, it indicates multiple errors like missing semicolon where there shouldn't be one and it doesn't recognize most variables. This is my script:

```
size(400, 400, P2D);

//Constructor canon
var Canon = function(canonX, canonY, W){
    this.canonX = canonX;
    this.canonY = canonY;
    this.W = W;
};

//CANON MOVELEFT
Canon.prototype.moveLeft = function(){
    this.canonX -= 10;
};
Canon.prototype.moveRight = function(){
    this.canonX += 10;
};

//Ball object
var Ball = function(x, y, width){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
};

Ball.prototype.draw = function(){
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.width);
}; 

Canon.prototype.shoot = function(){
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    var ball = new Ball(this.canonX + 15, this.canonY - 5, this.W/2, this.W/2);
    return ball;
};

//DRAW CANON
Canon.prototype.drawCanon = function(){
    quad(this.canonX - this.W/5, this.canonY + this.W * 2, this.canonX + 4/5 * this.W, 
this.canonY + 2 * this.W, this.canonX + 3 * this.W/5, this.canonY, this.canonX, this.canonY);
    ellipse(this.canonX + this.W/10 * 3, this.canonY + 2 * this.W, this.W, this.W/ 5 * 3);
    //wheels
    fill(138, 109, 23);
    ellipse(this.canonX - this.W/50 * 12, this.canonY + this.W/50 * 102, this.W/5 * 2, this.W/5 * 6);
    ellipse(this.canonX + this.W/50 * 42, this.canonY + this.W/50 * 102, this.W/5 * 2, this.W/5 * 6);
};

var canon = new Canon(172, 283, 50);
var boulet = null;
var boulet2 = null;
draw = function() {
    background(255, 255, 255);

    keyPressed = function(){
        if(keyCode === 37){
            canon.moveLeft();
        }
        else if(keyCode === 39){
            canon.moveRight();
        }
        else if(keyCode === 32){
            fill(0, 0, 0);
            if(boulet !== null && boulet.y > -15){
                boulet2 = canon.shoot();
            }else{
            boulet = canon.shoot();
            }
        }
    };
    canon.drawCanon();
    if(boulet !== null){
        boulet.draw();
        boulet.y -= 10;
    }
    if(boulet2 !== null){
        boulet2.draw();
        boulet2.y -= 10;
    }
};
```

Anybody has an idea why it's not working on processing 3?

Comment: Processing, the real Processing, is a typed language, and does not use `var`, nor untyped functions. While Processing.js was able to execute Processing code, the reverse is _not_ true. Processing cannot run Processing.js code without proper rewriting to the java syntax that Processing uses, first.

Comment: What should I use to make it work?

Comment: You should rewrite your code using Processing's syntax, which is a manual process.

Comment: But I don't see how it is possible to obtain te same code without variables and functions with arguments :s

Comment: no, not "without variables", without `var`. Processing doesn't use `var`, it is a strongly typed language and you need to actually indicate the data type, like `int` or `long` or `String` or `PVector[]`, etc. The same goes for functions: you need to specify the data type that the function returns, and each function parameter needs to be explicitly typed. https://processing.org/tutorials/gettingstarted/

Comment: Also note that there is no such thing as "assigning functions to variables" in Processing, things like your `Ball` need to be a `class` (which is good practice in modern JS, too. Try to avoid using a constructor function + `blah.prototype = {}` these days, use a normal class with a `constructor() { ... }`)